# Calling function in string.h file without object

Tags: c++, function, object

```
#include<string.h>

int a = 2;

string str = to_string(a);
```

I  want to know that in C++ whenever we want to call a library function we use

`library_object.function_name()` notation. But here we are directly using `to_string()` function without the using object. So my question is why we are not calling to_string() function like

`string_object.to_string();`

Also please specify what's the difference between the calling function here with and without the object.

Comment: `<string.h>` doesn't contain `std::string`.

Comment: Please read a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282) or at least the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) for the functionalities you use.

Comment: It's all about [functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions) vs [member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions).

Comment: `to_string` is supposed to return a string from the number you passed, so it would be rather strange if you would first need a string instance before you can call it

Answer (score 3):

You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be.

`std::to_string` is a function. Just a function. It's taking an `int` and giving back a `std::string`.

Here's another function:

```
void foo()
{
   // hello!
}
```

You don't *need* to make functions be member functions. C++ isn't *just* an object-oriented language.